# Python PIL place a pixel on the screen

Tags: python, image

I realize I can do what is shown here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library/Editing_Pixels.  Can I also use that for doing RGB/RGBA or only 8 bit color code???  It shows 8 bit in the sample code there I believe.  I'm not sure which way I want to go(RGB or 8 bit) so I want to be prepared for either option.  I'm trying to use PIL, hopefully for everything.

Also what is the correct setup for using setPixel.  I'm trying to research all my options and I know I remember seeing it being mentioned.

Is there any other ways of being able to plot a pixel on the screen using PIL?  I could probably use draw.line and just make the line one pixel big.

Comment: I thought 8 bit and RGB were the same thing. 0-255 makes eight bits per channel, right?

Comment: RGB has an 8 bit code for each of the RGB, 0-255 for red, green and blue.  8 bit, what I call a GIF image, I believe is only 8 bit, one channel, not 3.

Comment: Ok. In any case, the image generated by that sample code has more than 256 distinct colors, so it's definitely more than 8 bits per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the [sample](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library/Editing_Pixels) is using an RGB color model.  The line `pixels[i,j] = (i, j, 100)` sets the 8-bit red component to `i`, the 8-bit green component to `j`, and the 8-bit blue component to 100.  You can specify `'RGBA'` instead of `'RGB'` to get an (r,g,b,a) image.

PIL does support a `putpixel` ([docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)), but using `load` as the sample does and then indexing the result as a 2-D array is documented as being faster.

Comment: I should have guess given the sample image they had beside the code.  I was wandering how the heck they were creating the effect with the code.  I didn't even think about the i,j,100 being r,g,b.  Dumbness on my part.

Comment: Happens to all of us :) .  Would you please mark this as the correct answer so it won't clutter the "Unanswered" list?  Thanks!